# sqlFetch Table not found error

Tags: r, rodbc

After I use

```
cn<-odbcConnect(...)
```

to connect to MS SQL Server. I can successfully get data using:

```
tmp <- sqlQuery(cn, "select * from MyTable")
```

But if I use

```
tmp <- sqlFetch(cn,"MyTable")
```

R would complain about "Error in odbcTableExists(channel, sqtable) : table not found on channel". Did I miss anything here?

Comment: What is the output of `sqlTables(cn)`?

Comment: What is the result of `attributes(cn)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you work on Windows OS. When you define your "dsn" in Control panel > Administrative tools > System and Security > Data Sources (ODBC), you have to **select a database** as well. If you do that your code should work as expected.

So, the problem is not in your R code, but in your "dsn" string that in my opinion does not contain the reference to a database which is needed.

Comment: Thanks. I just kept clicking "Next" without selecting a default database in one the process. It works now.