# How to insert data to SQL Server table using R?

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, rodbc

I need help to write a simple data row to SQL server from R Language. (using RODBC or otherwise).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can write all the data (all rows) using `sqlSave(channel, data, rownames = FALSE)` where `channel <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=AAA;Uid=BBB;Pwd=CCC;")`. This will create a table with a name `data` in your database.

You can then append your existing table by `sqlQuery(channel, 'insert into table select * from data')`.

Comment: Table is already there, I am looking for a Insert Into Table type thing.

Comment: Updated the answer. The reason I usually use this approach is speed - it is much quicker than inserting row by row.