# MySQL and R, inserting more than 1000 rows at a time

Tags: mysql, r, bulk

I'm using R to insert a data.frame into a MySQL database. I have this code below that inserts 1000 rows at a time successfully. However, it's not practical if I have a data.frame with tens of thousands of rows. How would you do a bulk insert using R? is it even possible?

```
## R and MySQL
library(RMySQL)

### create sql connection object 
mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(), dbname="db", user='xxx', password='yyy', host='localhost', unix.sock="/Applications/MAMP/mysql/mysql.sock")

# get data ready for mysql 
df = data.format

# chunks 
df1 <- df[1:1000,]
df2 <- df[1001:2000,]
df3 <- df[2001:nrow(df),]

## SQL insert for data.frame, limit 1000 rows 
dbWriteTable(mydb, "table_name", df1, append=TRUE, row.names=FALSE)
dbWriteTable(mydb, "table_name", df2, append=TRUE, row.names=FALSE)
dbWriteTable(mydb, "table_name", df3, append=TRUE, row.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: What happens if you try to write it all at once with `dbWriteTable(mydb, "table_name", df)`?

Comment: Take a look at my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34591444/how-to-insert-data-to-sql-server-table-using-r/34591753#34591753. Although it speaks about SQL Server the same applies in your situation.

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, as the link suggests, write the df to a temp table and insert into the destination table as follows:

```
dbWriteTable(mydb, name = 'temp_table', value = df, row.names = F, append = F)
dbGetQuery(mydb, "insert into table select * from temp_table")
```

Comment: This has fixed soooo many things for me, I cant thank you enough! Thanks!

Comment: This trick really worked against many other solutions.

Comment: Isn't this just adding a step to what the OP already has, but not breaking up the data?

Comment: @StatsStudent Yes. The trick is using the DB. So essentially place the data in `temp_table` from R, then use SQL to append the data.

Answer (score 1):

Fast bulk insert is now supported by the DBI-based `ODBC` package, see
this example posted by Jim Hester (https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/34):

```
library(DBI);
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "MySQL")
dbWriteTable(con, "iris", head(iris), append = TRUE, row.names=FALSE)
dbDisconnect(con)
```

Since `RMySQL` is also DBI-based you just have to "switch" the DB connection
to use the `odbc` package (thanks to the standardized DBI interface of R).

Since the `RMySQL` package

> ... is being phased out in favor of the new `RMariaDB` package.

according to their web site (https://github.com/r-dbi/RMySQL) you could try switching the driver package to `RMariaDB` (perhaps they have already implemented a bulk insert feature).

For details see: https://github.com/r-dbi/RMariaDB

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, you could put it in a loop:

```r
for(i in 0:floor(nrow(df)/1000)) { 
  insert_set = df[(i*1000 + 1):((i+1)*1000),]
  dbWriteTable(mydb, "table_name", insert_set, append=T, row.names=F)
}
```