# How save data to SQL database quickly and in a bulk using R?

Tags: sql, r

I have following table:

```
structure(list(ID = c(9L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 13L), price= c(21040L, 
21056L, 63278L, 63280L, 63296L, 63312L, 63328L, 63344L, 32176L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 9L))
```

I want to save it using following code

```
dbSendUpdate(CONNECTION,paste("INSERT INTO DATABASE  (Date, Id, Price) VALUES (cast(TIMESTAMP 'NOW' as date), ",
                           df$ID,  
                           ", ",
                           df$price,
                           
                           ");"))
```

However, when I ran this code, only the first row is saved to database. How can I save the whole table with one command?

Comment: Which DB package are you using?

Comment: @Waldi Vertica and library(RJDBC)

Comment: do you use `DBI` with `RJDBC` as demonstrated [here](https://www.rforge.net/RJDBC/)?

Comment: @Waldi yes, exactly

Comment: does the table have exactly the columns you want to insert, or some other columns?

Answer (score 0):

You are just providing single row information to update into the table.
You can look into below two link.

https://www.r-bloggers.com/2015/07/how-to-write-an-r-data-frame-to-an-sql-table/

[How to insert data to SQL Server table using R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34591444/how-to-insert-data-to-sql-server-table-using-r)

Comment: these methods show how to create a new 'temporary' table and then join it with the table in SQL database. However, I cannot create tables in the database, only writing to the existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dbWriteTable` if the table isn't yet created and `dbAppendTable` after creation of the table :

```
library(RJDBC)
library(DBI)

drv <- JDBC("Driver setup")
conn <- DBI::dbConnect(drv, "JDBC connection", "user", "pwd")

# If the table doesn't already exist
DBI::dbWriteTable(conn,"TABLENAME",df)

# For an existing table
DBI::dbAppendTable(conn, "TABLENAME",df)
```

Depending on DB system, an alternative to `dbAppendTable` is:

```
dbExecute(conn,sqlAppendTable(ANSI(), "TABLENAME", df))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, however, I think this method works if I have the same number of columns and names in both SQL DB and R table. In reality, I have different names and a different numbers of columns.

Comment: Yes, this was my question : I'm going to update this

Comment: @priit Mets, I checked that the `dbExecute` solution also works when you don't supply all the columns, because [`sqlAppendTable` looks for the names of the supplied columns](https://github.com/r-dbi/DBI/blob/master/R/table-insert.R) . give it a try!

Comment: `dbAppendTable` should also work because it relies on  `sqlAppendTable`

Comment: I tried `dbExecute(vertica,sqlAppendTable(ANSI(), "TABLENAME", df[2]))` (only prices from my df). and got error
`Error in .verify.JDBC.result(r, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set",  : 
  Unable to retrieve JDBC result set
  JDBC ERROR: [Vertica][VJDBC](4856) ERROR: Syntax error at or near ","
  Statement: INSERT INTO "MYTABLE"
  ("price")
VALUES`

Comment: I won't be able to help more as I tested this on a SQL Server connection relying on RODBC. RJDBC might have a different behaviour when using `sqlAppendTable`